Langchain SharepointLoader - how to set my tenantID or directoryID to receive Oauth token
I am new to using Langchain libraries and have been struggling to find a solution to an Azure related error "AADSTS50194: Application xxxxx-xxxx-xxx--xxxxxxxxxxxxx is not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of /common endpoint is not supported for such applications ..... "
What I am doing in the application is basically setting up O365_client_id, o365_client_secret and initialiazing an instance of langchain's SharePointLoader. Behind the covers it is using O365 to obtain an oauth token with the correct scope to be able to read and load the contents of my sharepoint site.
I can get past the issue by switching the app registration to multi-tenant but that's not ideal and admittedly less secure. I understand that I need to somehow pass in my tenantID (or some may call it directory id) so that instead of using the default token endpoint of "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient" it will use my tenant specific endpoint of "https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/nativeclient.
My question is, how do I set my tenantID so o365 library will use that instead of the /common endpoint?
Thanks in advance!

I think you can just paste your tenant-id instead of the "/common/" in your URL, so it will be like:
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant-id/oauth2/nativeclient"
